# Jenkins Pipeline Branch - Name showing as %00

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcedx, jenkins, sfdx-plugin, jenkinsfile

I have a job created in Jenkins (Multibranch Pipeline). However, I am getting the Branch name as "%00" in the Jenkins UI. Can anyone suggest if there as a way to show anything meaningful instead of "%00"

[image]

Many thanks for help !!!

Comment: This question seems to be specifically about Jenkins and thus might be on topic at Stack Overflow. Is there a connection between this issue and your Salesforce configuration?

Comment: Hello David, I am sorry ... My bad. So I configured the Salesforce deploy job. Does that qualify this to be in this portal... Just assuming if someone from the community did it.

Comment: no apology necessary! Just want to make sure your question lands where it will find an answer. Right now, there may not be enough information to answer, but since the question is mostly about Jenkins behavior I suspect you'll find more expertise on SO.